# How to make a frama-c WP warning into an error?

Tags: warnings, frama-c

This warning is a fairly serious one that I would like to turn into an error. I spent a lot of time puzzling over why a proof was not working before realising that this warning really could not be ignored.

```
[wp] <my source code>.c:16: Warning: 
  Cast with incompatible pointers types (source: uint8*) (target: sint8*)
```

I believe that the answer should be something like

```
-wp-warn-key <category>=error
```

but I don't know how to find the category of "Cast with incompatible pointers types".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do that for this particular type of warning. Warning categories are a relatively new addition to Frama-C (appearing in [17.0 Chlorine](https://frama-c.com/html/changelog.html#Chlorine-20180501-17.0) according to the Changelog, i.e. in 2018), and not all warnings that predate this feature have been given a proper category. Since you can only set the behavior of a warning category, category-less warnings can only be warnings.

Warnings with a category will start with `[plugin-category]`, so that you can easily identify which category they belong to

Comment: Cheers! For now I'll just know not to ignore those warnings.